# Am I setting the value of the reference when changing a field of my class, or just the value of a value?

Tags: c#

I am writing a piece of code which involve a lot of duplication of data and operations and it is important to me that I minimise this as much as possible. The [MSDN support doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b0bdca4.aspx), to me, implies that when I set the field of my class `Foo` as an instance of some class `Bar` I am setting this as a reference to this instance, rather than the value, which is exactly what I want to do. Given how important this feature is to me however (it will affect the runtime of my program by orders) could someone wiser please confirm for me.

Code example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar ChildBar {get;set;}

    public void SetChildBarValue (int value)
    {
        this.ChildBar.Value = value;
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Value {get;set;}
}

var foo1 = new Foo();
var foo2 = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar();

foo1.ChildBar = bar;
foo2.ChildBar = bar;

foo1.SetChildBarValue(1);
Console.WriteLine(foo2.ChildBar.Value);
```

My question is, will the `WriteLine` return `1` or `null`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could always have just run this yourself to see the result!

Comment: you better search and learn more about the "Reference Types" and "Value Types"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, will the WriteLine return 1 or null?

As `Bar` is a declared as a `class`, hence a *reference type*, and you're setting both `ChildBar`'s to point to the same instance of `bar`, which results in a reference assignment to that `bar`, your `WriteLine` will print 1.

As a side note - actually running this code would have told you the same thing.

Comment: Thank you; I was worried about an exception to the rule as complexity ramped up. I'm not actually looking to set one `int` value, I want to asign a Task<SomeClass> several levels down. I felt asking the question had a better chance of someone commenting on the exceptions to the rule.

Comment: You should always strive to post an example which is accurate to the problem you're facing. That way we can nail the *real* problem you're facing instead of an easy abstract question.